# Regular expression, how to escape characters, specifically an asterisk

Tags: dart

How do you escape asterisks in Dart?

I have tested the following regular expression on regex101 tester

```
\*\*(.*?)\*\*
```

against the following string

```
find me **this** and **my other string** please
```

It finds two results ('this' and 'my other string') as expected.

In dart I get a warning in vscode 'use valid regular expression syntax' and it fails with the following error:

```
FormatException: Nothing to repeat**(.*?)**
```

I think my asterisks are not being escaped properly.  Is there a special way to escape asterisks in dart?  Here is a dartpad

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dbb38b6c97bbc16d994e71e27e9cda30

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fix this by using raw strings (prefixing the string literal with `r`

```
new RegExp(r"\*\*(.*?)\*\*");
```

or by escaping special characters

```
new RegExp("\\*\\*(.*?)\\*\\*");
```

Raw strings can't be used with string interpolation like `'my string $someVar foo'`, because raw means it takes all characters literally.

Comment: I just worked it out a second after I posted!  Many thanks Gunter and for all your other posts :-)

Answer (score 6):

if text comes from TextField use this:

```
RegExp.escape();
```

sample:

```
RegExp rex = RegExp('${RegExp.escape(searchText)}', caseSensitive: false, unicode: true);
```

Comment: You rock! Just what I needed Unrelated, but no need to interpolate single String: RegExp(RegExp.escape(searchText)) looks better.